# C:/android-ndk" is not found in PATH in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am try to clean the project but that give me error on console

> Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\server C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\lib\amd64 C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath C:\Windows\system32 C:\Windows C:\Windows\System32\Wbem C:\Windows\System32\WindosPowerShell\v1.0\ C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin C:\Android SDK\eclipse C:\android-ndk": Launching failed
>
> Error: Program "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/server C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/amd64 C:/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath C:/Windows/system32 C:/Windows C:/Windows/System32/Wbem C:/Windows/System32/WindosPowerShell/v1.0/ C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/bin C:/Android SDK/eclipse C:/android-ndk" is not found in PATH

How to Fix it i am also tryed some solution but it can't work
Thank You..

Comment: Does the path `C:/android-ndk` exist?  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Yes sir that have i keep the folder in to the C:\ drive which named  "android-ndk"

Comment: What did you actually run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide your NDK path in *Windows → Preferences*. On the left side there is an option called *Android*, click that and it will show NDK Option, there you can browse your NDK path.